# How to simplify spatial polygon using rmapshaper?

Tags: r, leaflet, rgdal

I am trying to simplify a spatial polygons dataframe with the following code:

```
library(rmapshaper)
library(rgdal)
countyshapes <- readOGR("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kjhealy/us-county/master/data/geojson/gz_2010_us_050_00_500k.json")
countyshapes <- ms_simplify(countyshapes, keep = 0.1)
```

But this returns the following error:

```
Error in sp::SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(polys, data = input@data) : 
  row.names of data and Polygons IDs do not match
```

Is there a way I can work around this error to simplify my SP object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran the code and if it worked, preferably update the `rmapshaper` package:

```
packageVersion("rmapshaper") 
#[1] ‘0.4.4’

countyshapes[1:5,]
#An object of class "SpatialPolygonsDataFrame"
#Slot "data":
#  GEO_ID STATE COUNTY      NAME   LSAD CENSUSAREA
#1 0500000US01029    01    029  Cleburne County    560.100
#2 0500000US01031    01    031    Coffee County    678.972
#3 0500000US01037    01    037     Coosa County    650.926
#4 0500000US01039    01    039 Covington County   1030.456
#5 0500000US01041    01    041  Crenshaw County    608.840
```

Another alternative is that you use the `sf::st_transform` function